# Making Python ignore CSV separator instruction

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

In line with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55068134/configuring-a-csv-file-and-reading-with-excel), Let's say we have the following `.csv` file to read with Python 3.7:

```
sep=,
A,B,C
1,2,3
4,"5,3",6
```

The Python code looks like this:

```
import csv

with open("tstSO.csv") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        thisA = row["A"]
        print(thisA)
```

Running this, I get `KeyError: 'A'` in the error message. If I remove the `sep=,` line, then I get the expected output:

```
1 
4
```

Is there a way I can make python ignore/skip the line that indicated the delimiter? The actual files I need to work with are very large, so it would not be nice to do copy operations or manipulations meddling with the whole file. Of course, I also need to make operations on other columns and values, the code above is just a minimal working example.

Comment: `next(csv_file)` right before `csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)` skips the first line

Comment: Just want to emphasize that the use of `csv.Sniffer()` in the answer to the linked duplicate question isn't needed here. Just skip the line as @PatrickArtner suggests.